# Download directory & subdirectories via wget

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, wget

I have a folder with folder view on the web (http://example.com/folder1/folder2/)

/folder2 has multiple folders with pdf files within them. I want download to my server via ssh all the content of /folder2 including all the sub folders and files using wget. I've tried the following but i keep getting only an index.html and robots.txt file.

```
[root@myserver downloads]# wget -r --no-parent --reject "index.html*" http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/
--2015-08-07 07:46:36--  http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/
Resolving www.example.com... 192.168.1.1
Connecting to www.example.com|192.168.1.1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: `www.example.com/folder1/folder2/index.html'

    [         <=>                           ] 4,874,325    138K/s   in 37s     

2015-08-07 07:47:42 (128 KB/s) -     `www.example.com/folder1/folder2/index.html' saved [4874325]

Loading robots.txt; please ignore errors.
--2015-08-07 07:47:42--  http://www.example.com/robots.txt
Connecting to www.example.com|192.168.1.1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 26 [text/plain]
Saving to: `www.example.com/robots.txt'

100%[======================================>] 26          --.-K/s   in 0s      

2015-08-07 07:47:42 (1.42 MB/s) - `www.example.com/robots.txt' saved [26/26]

Removing www.example.com/folder1/folder2/index.html since it should be rejected.

FINISHED --2015-08-07 07:47:42--
Downloaded: 2 files, 4.6M in 37s (128 KB/s)
[root@myserver downloads]#
```

Other commands that i've tried with similar FAILED results:

```
wget -m -p -E -k -K -np http://example.com/folder1/folder2/

wget -r http://example.com/folder1/folder2/ -nd -P /downloads -A PDF
```

Comment: first, if you have downloaded example.com that's right.... example.com has no more content than an index and robots

Comment: secondly, why do you change that much if you did not downloaded example.com

Comment: I can't seem to download anything other than an index.html file and a robots.txt file. There are folders and files in /folder2. I changed everything so that i won't have people going to example.com to download the actual files.

Comment: then I can't really help you because -r and --no-parent did work for me....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I want download to my server via ssh all the content of /folder2 including all the sub folders and files using wget.

I suppose you want to download via `wget` and SSH is not the issue here.

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6936095/248390) by [Attilio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/520558/attilio):

```
wget --mirror --page-requisites --adjust-extension --no-parent --convert-links \
    --directory-prefix=folder2 http://example.com/folder1/folder2/
```

### Edit

The above solution is well suited for mirroring websites; sorry I was a bit too quick to answer and it is not optimal for mirroring PDF.

```
wget -m -nH --cut-dirs=1 -np -R 'index.*' http://example.com/folder1/folder2/
```

- `-m`, `--mirror`: download recursively everything
- `-nH`, `--no-host-directories`: do not put the data inside a directory named with the host name
- `--cut-dirs=1`: skip the first directory when creating the local hierarchy
- `-np`, `--no-parent`: do not fetch the parents!
- `-R`, `--reject 'index.*'`: do not save files named like "index.*"

Might be useful: `-e robots=off` to tell wget to ignore your `robots.txt`.

#### Example

```
$ wget -m -nH --cut-dirs=4 -np --reject 'index.*' \
 http://ftp.lip6.fr/pub/linux/distributions/slackware/slackware64-current/source/a/bin/
$ tree
.
└── slackware64-current/
    └── source/
        └── a/
            └── bin/
                ├── banners.tar.gz
                ├── bin.SlackBuild
                ├── debianutils_2.7.dsc
                ├── debianutils_2.7.tar.gz
                ├── fbset-2.1.tar.gz
                ├── scripts/
                │   ├── diskcopy.gz
                │   └── xx.gz
                ├── slack-desc
                └── todos.tar.gz
```

## Alternative

This is not what you asked, but I personally like to use [`lftp`](http://lftp.yar.ru/) for that:

```
lftp -c "open http://example.com/folder1/; mirror folder2"
```

Comment: I used the lft option. Seems as though that's working perfectly. The wget option didn't work. It kept downloading only the index.html & robots.txt file. Thank you.

Comment: +1 for lftp. This is the only way i got to mirror jenkins plugins. Using the `wget` rejecting the index.html created the folder structure only with the hpi files.